# Use of GROUP BY in SQL -- only with aggregates?

Tags: sql, t-sql, group-by

is `GROUP BY` used only with aggregate functions ?
Can anyone give an example where it is used not in conjunction with aggregate functions.

Comment: `Group by` without any aggreegate function will work like query with `distinct`

Comment: That would work the same way as distinct. Select distinct name from <table>. Select name from <table> group by name

Comment: Dont forget to mark asnwer as accepted if you got the info you want

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SELECT with GROUP BY can be used as an alternative to SELECT DISTINCT. Pranay Rana's example is essentially equivalent to

```
SELECT DISTINCT UserName, Departmentid FROM user
```

If you want an example where the preference of GROUP BY over DISTINCT is justified, here's one. Say, you want to return items that only occur once in a table:

```
SELECT Item
FROM atable
GROUP BY Item
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

As you can see, the query only returns a non-aggregated column.

It still uses an aggregate function, though, even if not in the SELECT clause. There *may* be situations where you must prefer GROUP BY to DISTINCT while not needing to use aggregate functions *at all*, but I'll have to be platform specific at this point.

In particular, if you are using SQL Server, you will find a difference between the results of the following two statements:

#1:

```
WITH data (f) AS (
  SELECT 'abc' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'def' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'abc'
)
SELECT f, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY f) FROM data GROUP BY f
```

#2:

```
WITH data (f) AS (
  SELECT 'abc' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'def' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'abc'
)
SELECT DISTINCT f, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY f) FROM data
```

(If you aren't, you can still see the results for yourself using [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new).)

Both statements are meant to return distinct items ranked. However, only the first statement (with GROUP BY) returns the results as expected, while the latter (with DISTINCT) returns *all* items. <s>Obviously, ranking functions in SQL Server are evaluated after GROUP BY, but before DISTINCT</s> The reason is, the SELECT clause [in SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx) is evaluated after GROUP BY, but before DISTINCT, which makes you prefer GROUP BY over DISTINCT in this case. (Thanks @ypercube for nudging me in the right direction.)

Comment: Your last example would also work without ranking functions but with an ordinary function. `SELECT f, RAND() FROM data GROUP BY f` vs. `SELECT DISTINCT f, RAND() FROM data`

Comment: OK, it would **not** work with `RAND()` in SQL-Server. It would work with `NEWID()`.

Comment: Yes, and I can now see why. Updated my answer. Thanks for the comments!

Comment: Arguably your second example does use an aggregate (`COUNT()`) ;) I anticipate the next question: "Use of HAVING in SQL — only with GROUP BY?" :)

Comment: @onedaywhen: Andriy states that: *"It still uses an aggregate function, though, even if not in the SELECT clause"*

Comment: @ypercube: Sure, they acknowledged that case is not relevant but I still urge them to remove it. Good answer otherwise and got my upvote regardless.

Comment: @onedaywhen: I don't mind removing that example. I agree that it may *turn out* irrelevant, yet I am not convinced that it actually is. It is not entirely clear what the OP wants. Maybe they want to know whether it can ever make sense to have a query with GROUP BY that *returns* non-aggregated data only (but may still be aggregating columns at other stages e.g. for filtering purposes). Or perhaps they are interested in an example of a GROUP BY query without *any* aggregating whatsoever which, however, would still have practical sense.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this  where I have not applied any aggregate function

```
Select City,State from geodata group by City,State
```